# Is it possible to monkey patch Django's reverse?

Tags: python, django, monkeypatching

Some of our urls include `#`. These are used for reverse lookup, both using `reverse` and the `{% url` template tag (which uses `reverse` internally). Django 1.8 used to leave it alone, 1.11 now encodes it to `%23`.

Is it possible to put a monkey patch wrapper somewhere and have it be used everywhere without fail? Here's the wrapper I have:

```
def patch_reverse(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print "inner reverse"
        url = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return url.replace("%23", "#")

    return inner


from django.urls import base
base.reverse = patch_reverse(base.reverse)
```

The `print` statement is so I can see if it's actually running.

I've tried putting it in settings, the `__init__` of the first installed app, and in the `urls` of the first installed app. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. In your `settings.py` or equivalent settings module:

```
from django import urls
from django.core import urlresolvers

_django_reverse = urlresolvers.reverse


def _reverse(*args, **kwargs):
    result = _django_reverse(*args, **kwargs)
    # Do whatever you want to do to reverse here
    return result.replace("%23", "#")


urlresolvers.reverse = _reverse
urls.reverse = _reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time you've patched `reverse` the original function may have already been imported into `django.urls` (where you usually import it from) and `django.template.defaulttags` (where the `{% url %}` tag uses it. Try patching it in those modules instead:

```
import django.urls
django.urls.reverse = patch_reverse(django.urls.reverse)

import django.template.defaulttags
django.template.defaulttags = patch_reverse(django.template.defaulttags)
```

Comment: It isn't even working in `./manage.py shell`. Is there some dynamic source reloading of the original module that I can patch?

Comment: Patching `django.urls.reverse` in `manage.py shell` worked for me when I tested it.